# HBase AggregationClient in HDInsight

Tags: c#, azure, hbase, azure-hdinsight

I am trying out the C# REST client accessing HBase in HDInsight.
I would like to get a filtered row count without bringing results down to the client, and from what I've seen online, the AggregationClient coprocessor seems to be what I need. But I haven't been able to find any documentation as to whether it's available in HBase in HDInsight, and more specifically, available to the REST client.
Anyone have any experience with it, or suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Any processing on server that needs to be done, I typically end up mapping the HBase table to a hive table and leveraging the hive connection drivers or for it for C# or via the Hive Type Provider in F#...

Mapping HBase to Hive:
http://indiedevspot.com/2015/07/09/powering-azureml-with-hadoop-hbase/ (about 1/4 down)

Linq to Hive (C#):
http://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/

Hive Type Provider F#:
http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.HiveProvider/

Comment: Since I posted my question, my team has been working with Phoenix, which implements much of the server-side processing I need. Using Phoenix does open its own can of worms, however.  Thanks for the reply.